# Ganache-cli Fork unlocked account to make transactions

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli

I'm trying to use ganache-cli on a fork of the Main Network.

I use the following command to start ganache.

ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY -- unlock 0x6EBaF477F83E055589C1188bCC6DDCCD8C9B131a

Ganache will still give me the 10 account and non of them have this address.

This account is not mine but has a lot of ether in it. So how do I work on the fork with this account?

Truffle will also see me as the first ganache account. And contract deployment will be made under this address and not the one I unlocked.

How do I work from this account without the private key?

It' seam like truffle isn't seeing this unlocked account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the "from" sender account.

If you're trying to make a contract interaction (functional call), then you want something like

`MyContract.someFunction(arg1, arg2, { from: "0x6EBaF477F83E055589C1188bCC6DDCCD8C9B131a" })`

If you're trying to send ETH from the unlocked account, then you want something like

```
const someAccount = "0x6635f83421bf059cd8111f180f0727128685bae4"
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: "0x6EBaF477F83E055589C1188bCC6DDCCD8C9B131a", to: someAccount, value: "1000000000000000000"})
```

Comment: How's web3 client going to sign this transaction without the private key? Does Ganache treat unlocked accounts differently and never check for the signature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the connect option of ethers too.
But you'll have to derive the signer of the unlocked account by calling

```
signer = provider.getSigner(unlockedAccountAddress)
```

Then to make a transaction from that account, simply

```
myContract.connect(signer).myFunction()
```

Answer (score -1):

From [ganache-cli documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#options):

> Specify `--unlock` ... any number of times passing either an address or an account index to unlock specific accounts. When used in conjunction with `--secure`, `--unlock` will override the locked state of specified accounts.

So you obviously need to add `--secure` when you start ganache-cli.