# Send transaction from unlocked account using Golang in Ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ganache

Ganache allows unlocking accounts for sending transactions impersonating other Ethereum accounts.

Based on [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/93069/83282) answer, for an unlocked account you can send a transaction with web3.js like this:

```
const someAccount = "0x6635f83421bf059cd8111f180f0727128685bae4"
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: "0x6EBaF477F83E055589C1188bCC6DDCCD8C9B131a", to: someAccount, value: "1000000000000000000"})
```

This works in JS, however, when trying to do a similar thing in Golang, I noticed the `from` field of transactions is not exported:

```
type Transaction struct {
    inner TxData    // Consensus contents of a transaction
    time  time.Time // Time first seen locally (spam avoidance)

    // caches
    hash atomic.Value
    size atomic.Value
    from atomic.Value
}
```

I tried setting that filed using reflection but noticed it is ignored when go-ethereum client sends transactions:

```
func (ec *Client) SendTransaction(ctx context.Context, tx *types.Transaction) error {
    data, err := tx.MarshalBinary()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return ec.c.CallContext(ctx, nil, "eth_sendRawTransaction", hexutil.Encode(data))
}
```

`MarshalBinary` method only cares about the `inner` field of the transaction and skips `from`:

```
func (tx *Transaction) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    if tx.Type() == LegacyTxType {
        return rlp.EncodeToBytes(tx.inner)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := tx.encodeTyped(&buf)
    return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

Is there any easy way for impersonating unlocked accounts using Go? Any ideas are appreciated.